# Multiple Views 1 View Controller transition animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a weather app. I let users add new locations which means there should be a way for the user to view the weather data for the new location. Right now I have 1 ViewController which handles a swipe gesture. If the user swipes right/left new data appears until they run out of locations. The problem is I have no transition. I want to add a transition animation to mimic a slide animation transition that there normally would be while moving from ViewController A to ViewController B.

I don't know how to go on and implement this.

Comment: Why not use a `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: Check out the link http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path . Not sure if it helps.

Comment: @HAS Didn't know what UIPageViewController is, shall check it out.

Comment: http://www.purushukla.com/2013/02/new-slide-out-animation-for-ios.html

Comment: Can you post some of your code? - If you are just using one viewController does this mean you are presenting your info in UIViews? - it's hard to help without seeing what you've tried.

Comment: @Wezly I don't think code will help much. All my code does is change the data array being used as data source when user swipes. When you swipe, data for new location pops up with no transition. I want the transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use a `UIPageViewController` as @HAS told you before. Here is a good link to start with: [iOS 7 UIPageViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)

Basically apple's weather app uses the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for.

https://github.com/comyarzaheri/Sol

Comment: actually the link you provided is the weather application itself if im not mistaken. But what nupac wants is a uiview transition that mimics the uiviewcontroller pushvc